# Display @@ROWCOUNT in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

How to display `@@ROWCOUNT` in method after I execute a stored procedure? I want to count how many rows are affected after `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements have been executed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADProcTemp]
    @Username varchar(250),
    @DisplayName varchar(70),
    @isEnabled tinyint,
    @PassNevExp tinyint,
    @rowcount int OUT
AS
    --SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 PrezimeIme FROM [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD] WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   WHERE NetworkLogin = @Username)
    BEGIN
        IF(@isEnabled = 1 OR @PassNevExp = 1)
             INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD](NetworkLogin, PrezimeIme, Status, PassNevExp)
             VALUES (@Username, @DisplayName, @isEnabled, @PassNevExp)

        SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
        RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;   
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[tblZaposleni_AD]
        SET Status = @isEnabled,        
            PassNevExp = @PassNevExp
        WHERE NetworkLogin = @Username 
          AND (Status <> @isEnabled OR [PassNevExp] <>@PassNevExp)
    END
END
```

C# code:

```
public void ExcStrPrc(string Username, string DisplayName, bool isEnable, bool PassNevExp)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADProcTemp", conn);          
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username.ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DisplayName", DisplayName.ToString().Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isEnabled", Convert.ToInt32(isEnable));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassNevExp", Convert.ToInt32(PassNevExp));
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowcount", SqlDbType.Int);

    SqlParameter rowsAffected = new SqlParameter("@rowcount", SqlDbType.Int);
    rowsAffected.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(rowsAffected);

    int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (k != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uspjesno insertovano ! ");
    }

    int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());          
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are only assigning @rowcount=@@ROWCOUNT in the insert branch, not the update branch, that seems wrong. Also you are not using "rowsAffected" in your c# code, instead you are using the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. Why?

Comment: The reason why I didnt put @rowcount=@@ROWCOUNT in UPDATE is that I firsty want to test my INSERT function.

Comment: Also - don't execute your query **twice**! You have `int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and a few lines further down `int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` - remove that second call!

Comment: Yes, I see. I remove alredy. Thank you !

Comment: Whatever I change in code, I didnt get any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value of the OUT parameter once the sp has been executed:

```
var effectedRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@rowCount"].Value);
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'SqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no accessible extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)

Comment: @Robby - sorry, updated. I was using DynamicParameters, but altered now to use SqlParameters

Comment: After int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Lemme check what will happen now

Comment: Whatevery I do, rowsAffected doesnt return anythink

Comment: @Robby make sure you SET NO COUNT OFF. You also don't need RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;

Comment: Yes, I disable SET NO COUNT OFF

Comment: @Robby - have you tested your SQL query and that 'rowCount' gets populated correctly?

Comment: How to test it ? Have no idea ?

Comment: So when you run your whole query above you can confirm that at the end if you add PRINT @rowCount you get a value?

Comment: Sure, I get result at the end

Comment: @Robby - now you've SET NOCOUNT OFF when you debug does 'k' have a value? You shouldn't really need an output parameter as [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery) returns the number of effected rows by default for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Uspjesno insertovano ! ", effectedRows); 
`effectedRows` show 1 when it's insert, but I want after all data is inserted display total number of inserted value

Comment: k is always 0, effectedRows is 0 also